# How do I politely say that I am not applying to my alma mater anymore?

Tags: phd, etiquette, academic-life

I am a PhD student in Y university in United States and I finished my MS in X university before my PhD. All professors who provided my recommendation letters work for X. Lately, I have been feeling that I made the wrong choice coming to Y and wanted to go to back to X and talked to my professors from X university. They were very sympathetic to my concerns and agreed to recommend me again for X university. I don't think I am applying to X anymore and will stay in Y. How do I get back to my professors about this? I wish to maintain a cordial relationship with them.

Comment: “Thank you again for offering to write a recommendation letter for me. After serious consideration, however, I have decided to stay at Y, so I will not need your recommendation letter after all.”